# Holomorphic bijection between slit plane and upper half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find an example of a holomorphic bijection from $H := \{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid Im(z) > 0\}$ to $M := \mathbb{C} - (-\infty,0]$ and visa versa. I feel like the a branch of the complex logarithm might be useful here but am struggling to figure out exactly how.

Comment: Inevitably you'll need a function with  a branch cut on the negative real axis. Log is certainly one such function, but there's another familiar function that will do the trick here. What functions with branch cuts can you think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map $L(z) = \sqrt{z}$ with the principal branch ie with a cut along the negative real axis. This will conformally map $M$ to the right half plane, $U : = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}| Re(z) > 0 \}$. Then use the rotation, $z \rightarrow e^{i\pi/2}z$ to map $U$ conformally to $H$. Then the inverse of the composition of the above maps will be your desired  holomorphic bijection from $H$ to $M$.